# another php/mysql injection using TinyMCE

Tags: php, mysql

I'm no php programmer, only site admin, I've recently adopted a site with web panel that causes sql injection when trying to post html code in TinyMCE, containing apostrophe.

Problematic html code;

```
img onmouseover="this.src='layout/gfx/wiecej1.png'
```

php code;

```
$edytuj = $_POST['edytuj'];
```

sql query;

```
if($edytuj) {
     $podstrony_id = $_POST['id'];
     $podstrony_id_kategorie = $_POST['id_kategorie'];
     $podstrony_id_moduly = $_POST['id_moduly'];
     $podstrony_tytul = $_POST['tytul'];
     $podstrony_szablon = $_POST['szablon'];
     $podstrony_tresc = $_POST['tresc'];
     $podstrony_aktywnosc = $_POST['aktywnosc'];

     $zapytanie = "UPDATE $tab_podstrony SET id_kategorie='$podstrony_id_kategorie', id_moduly='$podstrony_id_moduly', tytul='$podstrony_tytul', szablon='$podstrony_szablon', tresc='$podstron$
     $wynik = mysql_query($zapytanie);
```

Site uses php-cgi-5.4.39 and mysql-5.5
I don't have access to previous environment (where this panel worked fine), so
I can't find out if it's configuration or code problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick fix:** you need to properly escape any strings you want to include in the query using [mysql_real_escape_string()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

**Proper fix:** switch to `mysqli`, as the `mysql` extension is deprecated, and either escape the strings with [mysqli_real_escape_string()](https://php.net/manual/ro/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), or better use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Or switch to [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: And yet the OP is trying to handle SQL injection :)

Comment: No, I'm saying the OP is asking about it and the programming differences between MySQLi and PDO are not far apart.

Comment: [It isn't as simple as adding an `i`.](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059) If you want SQL injection protection you have to change all of your queries to parametrized queries. There is quite a bit of work involved. Not to mention that MySQLi has had some issues.

Comment: Thanks for all advices, I've forwarded them to dev. guys, as I know they're implementing pdo on this project.